# Pearson Correlation vs. ANOVA

Tags: correlation, anova, pearson-r

I have a continuous independent variable (MOCA scores), and a continuous dependent variable (Physical Fitness score).

I would like to use a Spearman/Pearson linear correlations (continuous MOCA score vs. continuous fitness score) to determine the relationship.

However, I also have transformed the continuous independent variable (MOCA scores) into four categories (no impairment, mild impairment, moderate impairment, and severe impairment) because I am interested in the different mean scores of fitness based on cognitive class. However, as a rule, given continuous data, you should never arbitrarily divide it into high/medium/low catogories in order to do an ANOVA. Doing so throws away information in multiple ways.

Would doing an ANOVA be like double-counting? A second test of significance may be unnecessary, but I still want to report the results of the different cognitive classes (even if it is simply a table of means).

Comment: what is your hypothesis about relation between the two postulates/variables?  Is there an inverse relation ? need to know for correct tabulation!